# Сортировка строк и буква ё с++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, строки, сортировка

Нужно отсортировать слова, например: ёжик, Азбука, аромат, Ёж. Проблема в том, что буква ё не сортируется.

```
#include <exception>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int element;
    string number;
    cin >> element;
    auto l = list<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < element; i++) {
        cin >> number;
        l.push_back(number);
    }

    l.sort();

    for (auto iterator = l.begin(); iterator != l.end(); ++iterator)
    {
        cout << *iterator << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это потому, что для C++ строка — набор байт, и она про Unicode ничего не знает. Сортировать нужно в определённой _локали_. (Разные языки имеют разные представления о порядке _одних и тех же_ букв.)

Comment: Кодировка-то какая? cp1251?

Comment: Еще один аргумент против этой буквы.

Comment: @avp, а при чём здесь буква? Не сама же она себя запихала в непонятное место кодовой таблицы.

Comment: я бы начал смотреть с этого http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357374/locale-dependent-ordering-for-stdstring

Comment: @Arhad, конечно не сама. Но то, что ее пришлось именно *куда-то запихивать*, как раз и говорит о ее месте в нашем языке.

Comment: Вы не поверите, но в других языках такие же проблемы. В немецком (двойная s), в греческом и так далее.

Comment: Как ни странно, в [справке о локалях в C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/operator()) есть рабочий пример для русского языка.

Answer (score 3):

При сортировке списка из string строки сравниваются по-символьно (побайтно). В зависимости от типа кодирования байт будут разные результаты сравнения. Во всех популярных кодировках, а именно в Unicode, CP866 (DOS), CP1251 (Windows) во всех у них буква Ё/ё стоят где-то в отдельном месте от алфавита, это означает сравнение букв не будет давать порядок как в эталонном русском алфавите. Но проблема решаема, т.к. у функции сортировки можно указать свою функцию сравнения элементов. `l.sort([](string const & l, string const & r)->bool{ /* Сравнить l и r */ });` при этом нужно реализовать код внутри так чтобы сравнить две строки l и r учитывая специфику буквы Ё/ё, код должен возвращать true если l < r иначе false. Также чтобы решить проблемы с кодировками можно просто в каком то виде вначале прочитать строки, а потом их сконвертировать в Unicode и уже в юникоде делать сравнения, либо привязаться к какой то кодировке, это не важно в какой кодировке Ё/ё по особому сравнивать. Вот привожу почти весь нужный код, подходит для строк в кодировках CP866 и CP1251 (для юникода тоже вполне может подойти только вместо char нужно uint32_t или char32_t):

```
// Где-то выше определить функцию CharOrder.
inline uint32_t CharOrder(char c) {
    if (c == 'ё') return uint32_t(uint8_t('е')) * 2 + 1;
    if (c == 'Ё') return uint32_t(uint8_t('Е')) * 2 + 1;
    return uint32_t(uint8_t(c)) * 2;
}

....

// Где нужно сортировать список l из строк, написать.
l.sort([](std::string const & a, std::string const & b)->bool{
    return std::lexicographical_compare(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), [](char a, char b)->bool{
        return CharOrder(a) < CharOrder(b);
    });
});
```

Comment: а зачем в вашем кусочке кода лямбда-функция, неужели нельзя обойтись без неё?

Comment: @mymedia можно и без лямбда, но лямбда я считаю самый удобный вариант, особенно если код будет коротким. Если длинный то можно вынести во внешнюю функцию сравнения и вместо лямбды передавать указатель на эту функцию. Я просто хотел сделать акцент что CustomIsLess это некий код а не функция, если функция тогда её можно и использовать вместо лямбды.

Comment: Было бы интересно увидеть сам сравнивающий код. Можно код очередного символа умножать на два, но если это Ё, давать ей нужное нечетное значение. Однако, если известна длина строк, то может захотеться сортировать 8-байтными блоками, вот тут Ё создаёт неразрешимую проблему.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Код для сравнения вроде очень примитивный, да можно просто юникод номер умножать на два, а если это ё тогда просто давать ей нечётный код между е и ж и также сравнивать.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Вот специально по вашему запросу написал основной код для сравнения.

Answer (score 1):

```js
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <locale>
#include <vector>
 
template<typename T>
static void PrintList(const std::list<T>& l)
{
    std::cout << "List: ";
    for (auto iterator = l.begin(); iterator != l.end(); ++iterator)
    {
        std::cout << *iterator << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
 
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {     
    system("chcp 1251");
    std::list<std::string> l = {  "ёлка", "Еда", "аббат", "жеод" };
    PrintList(l);
 
    l.sort(std::locale(""));
 
    PrintList(l);
 
 
    return 0;
}
```